# Is there a way to display the current initialization parameters that are in effect for a database?

Tags: firebird

If I set a parameter in firebird.conf how to be sure that Firebird took my change?
For example:

I a set the parameter CpuAffinityMask to 15 in Windows with Firebird 2.5 with SuperServer how to be sure that Firebird is using 4 cores/cpus?

Edit:

Is there an administrative view that displays the current initialization parameters that are in effect for the database? (like v$parameter in Oracle)

Answer (score 0):

For changes in Firebird.conf to be effective you need to restart Firebird. You have to belive to programmers who made Firebird it is using conf file. There is no reason not to belive.

Comment: Is there an administrative view that displays the current initialization parameters that are currently in effect for the database?